# Can't insert data java mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, insert

I have a problem i can't insert data into database I use Java and mysql

```
try {
        String query1 = "insert into Client(Codecli,Nom,Ville,Datenais,Solde,Password) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query1);
        statement.setString(1, num.getText());
        statement.setString(2, nomField.getText());
        statement.setString(3, villeField.getText());
        statement.setDate(4, null);
        statement.setDouble(5, 0.0);
        statement.setString(6, passwordField.getText());
        statement.executeUpdate(query1);
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It show this error

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).

Comment: `statement.executeUpdate(query1);` is wrong, see documentation; there must be a method for executing without parameters

Comment: Thanks! I remove the parameter and it worked

Answer (score 2):

```
// prepared statements must be closed, so use a try-with-resources (or a try / catch / finally) 
// connection should not be closed in the try block because throwing an exception will leave it open.
try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query1);connection) {
    statement.setString(1, num.getText());
    statement.setString(2, nomField.getText());
    statement.setString(3, villeField.getText());
    statement.setDate(4, null);
    statement.setDouble(5, 0.0);
    statement.setString(6, passwordField.getText());
    
    // no parameters in executeUpdate() (your original problem)
    int result = statement.executeQuery();
    // returns the number of rows affected --- so a 0 = didn't work

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

full disclaimer - I didn't test this code, but I'm 99% sure if you make these changes it'll work.

Comment: Thanks! I just removed the parameter in executeUpdate and it worked